# Dynamic import of json files in react - what am I getting wrong?

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, internationalization

The directory each of our components live in will also be joined with multiple json files (these are translation files used for internationalizing our app). I'm trying to achieve something where I only import the translation file that needs to be used (depending on the locale provided) and not import all the others. Just playing around with this, I found several approaches that didn't work, such as:

```
 const paths = {
   "en-US": "@alias/components/Prefs/Component/lang/en-compiled.json",
   "pt-BR": "@alias/components/Prefs/Component/lang/pt-br-compiled.json"
 };

const Billing = ({ account_id, intl }) => {
  const localeContext = useContext(LocaleContext);

   import(paths[localeContext.locale]).then(module => {
     console.log(module);
   });
...
```

Here I was just trying to log out the contents of the json file to see if it was even being reached. However, I kept getting errors like so:
[image]

And I received the same errors for similar approaches. However, the one approach that did output my json contents, though seemingly the same, was just this:

```
  import(
    "@alias/components/Prefs/Component/lang/en-compiled.json"
  ).then(module => console.log(module.default));
```

What on earth is the difference between the two? Why does strictly placing the string in my import statement work, while referencing the string from a dictionary does not? If the first approach would work, it would be easy to import exactly what I need, but it's not seeming to get along with me.

Comment: Did you verify that `localeContext` is what you think it is supposed to be?

Comment: What bundler are you using?

Comment: @dmikester1 yep, it is. In my case, it came back as "en-US" so it should have mapped to the import string I defined with it. Which it did, but it acts as if it can't find it.

Comment: @MattPeng webpack, if that answers your question?